# Display php array on a fix html table without affecting the number of rows

Tags: php, html

I am still in the process of learning PHP and would like to seek for your assistance regarding my concern. I already know how to display an array into an html table which i usually do with my forms. Then suddenly i came into this issue wherein there should be a fix table with a fix number of rows (lets say about 5 rows).

Now if i would display information coming from a specific user and that user only has 2 rows of data from mysql then i will only have 2 rows displayed on my html table.

What happens:

```
*****************
** A ** B ** C **
*****************
** 1 ** 2 ** 3 **
*****************
** 4 ** 5 ** 6 **
*****************
```

What i want as an output:

```
*****************
** A ** B ** C **
*****************
** 1 ** 2 ** 3 **
*****************
** 4 ** 5 ** 6 **
*****************
**   **   **   **
*****************
**   **   **   **
*****************
```

Is there a neat way to code this. Your idea is already a big help; I am not asking for codes but you can somehow guide me on what i can do here in order to achieve the output i want.

Thanks.

Comment: Count the rows you get from mysql. If less than desired, add some more rows to your table in another loop.

Comment: so output extra rows if the database results are "smaller" than what your table should be.

Comment: thanks @Michel i am getting the idea now ill give that a try and will update my results but i believe this is what i need

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys still trying out all those advises you provided. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain a second counter with your fixed number calculations.  In pseudo-code, it might look like this:

```
$rowCount = 0;
while (getNextDataRow()) {
    printDataRow();
    $rowCount++;
}
while ($rowCount <= 5) {
    printEmptyRow();
    $rowCount++;
}
```

Note that this would add empty rows when needed, but it wouldn't constrain the number of rows if the data contains *more than* 5.  It's up to you what to do in that case.  The data query could have a `LIMIT` to prevent that from happening, the first `while` loop could have a check for `$rowCount == 5` and exit the loop, etc.

Comment: thanks @David i am getting the idea now ill give that a try and will update my results but i believe this is what i need

Comment: you nailed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop with an `if` statement. Something like this:

```
$myData = array(
    array('A', 'B', 'C'),
    array('1', '2', '3'),
    array('4', '5', '6')
);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    if (isset($myData[$i]))
    {
        echo '<td>'.$myData[$i][0].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$myData[$i][1].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$myData[$i][2].'</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill your array with empty strings till its count is 5:

```
$array = array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5,6));
for($i=0, $add = 5-count($array);$i<$add;$i++){
    $array[]=array('','','');
}
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 5
      2 => int 6
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
```